# Using Google Cloud Function Python to save CSV to Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Hello I am making an API request using Python and I want to export the CSV file to Google Cloud Storage

This code works in my local machine however, how can I export the csv file to google bucket/storage?

```
import requests

import csv


request = requests.get(f'https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/scores/json/TeamSeasonStats/2022?key=')

nba_team_stats = request.json()

data_file = open('nba_team_stats.csv', 'w')

csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

count = 0

for stats in nba_team_stats:
    if count == 0:
        header = stats.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1
    csv_writer.writerow(stats.values())
data_file.close()
```

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample

Comment: how do i export as csv file?

Comment: Edit your question to improve. It is not clear what your problem is. What is the problem and what is the error?

Comment: the problem is that google cloud function doesnt accept the way i write my csv files , so i need to write it into google storage rather than local

Comment: If you want a fuller example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68854786/59867

Comment: @jay have you also tried this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59799941/writing-a-new-file-to-a-google-cloud-storage-bucket-from-a-google-cloud-function/70366028#70366028)?

Comment: Use the client library and write to Cloud Storage. You only write locally here.